# alternativa a selenium webdriver para php

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver

Estoy buscando una alternativa a Selenium WebDriver para php, que se pueda ejecutar en un entorno servidor sin entorno gráfico, y al ser un servidor compartido, debiera ser sin instalación

Un Saludo.

Comment: ¿Has comprobado la funcion headless de selenium?

Comment: No encuentro documentacion o al respecto, ¿dispones algo?